# How to give a link with href to a text html through jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the below HTML

```
<h4 style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.6; color: red;">
   <b>Test</b>
</h4>
```

to the below HTML.

```
<h4 style="text-align: center; line-height: 1.6; color: red;">
   <a href="www.asdfasdf.com"><b>Test</b></a>
</h4>
```

By using jQuery, how can I add a tag to a HTML tag?

Comment: Should the `<b>` element always be wrapped with an `<a>` with that specific URL, if not how should the content influence the URL of the `<a>` element? Can you show what you've tried, and explain what didn't work (and in what way it didn't work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this could make what you want:

```
// Create new content of h4
var newContent = '<a href="www.asdfasdf.com">' + $("h4").html() + '</a>';
// Clear content of h4
$("h4").empty();
// Append new content inside h4
$("h4").append(newContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is following - first, we need to create the href tag with the content of our current h4 inside:

```
$('<a href="www.asdfasdf.com">').html($('h4').html())
```

Constructing our href tag, we can replace the h4-s content with it. In one line, that will look like this:

```
$('h4').html($('<a href="www.asdfasdf.com">').html($('h4').html()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('h4').html(`<a href="www.asdfasdf.com"><b>Test</b></a>`)
```